# I got this JSON error when getting token in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express, http, mean

I have this header x-token added

[postman config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDZJ1.png)

I set my token saved in localStorage by using headers in Angular service:

```
validateToken(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('x-token', localStorage.getItem('token') || '');
    return this.authService.get("/api/auth/relogin",{headers})
}
```

I subscribe info in other component:

```
login(){
    this.authService.validateToken().subscribe(token => console.log(token));
}
```

What i got is this error:

[error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2b6L.png)

I've tried to do configs in the request, i've seen solutions like adding responseType:'text' and more like that, but when doing it, the subscribe info shows this in console:

[console log info when adding responseType:'text'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7RRO.png)

Comment: `/api/auth/relogin` returns HTML text not JSON. Check your api server.

Comment: I guess your api is returning the index.html of your angular project., there is probably a problem with your api url.

is authService a custom service, or HttpCLient ?